# Dpkg and Apt unsynced after upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kubuntu, dpkg

I've recently run out of space on my root partition and have been trying to free up space.

I updated from 18.04 a few months ago now, the update seemingly went ok but after looking into it, it looks like there's a lot of packages that have hung around that probably shouldn't have. Now I can't access them.

I found this command to list packages installed and the size of packages

```
dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Package;-50}\t${Installed-Size}\n' | sort -k 2 -n | grep -v deinstall | awk '{printf "%.3f MB \t %s\n", $2/(1024), $1}'


206.011 MB       firefox
206.761 MB       libnvidia-gl-450
214.736 MB       golang-1.13-go
216.437 MB       openjdk-11-jdk-headless
218.788 MB       openjdk-11-dbg
224.924 MB       google-chrome-stable
242.558 MB       teams
246.144 MB       openjdk-13-jdk-headless
255.206 MB       zoom
260.329 MB       libgl1-mesa-dri
271.228 MB       insomnia
271.582 MB       openjdk-11-doc
279.099 MB       libgl1-mesa-dri
314.970 MB       fonts-noto-extra
388.194 MB       azuredatastudio
417.396 MB       wine-stable-i386
480.034 MB       wine-stable-amd64
511.167 MB       linux-firmware
536.146 MB       azure-cli
1019.688 MB      mssql-server
```

So I've been trying to uninstall mssql-server and insomnia and a few other packages.

```
tom@Stradale:~$ sudo apt remove mssql-server insomnia
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mssql-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'insomnia' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Apt can't find the package but it is clearly shown in dpkg. If I run

```
sudo apt update

Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/mssql-server-2019 bionic InRelease
```

I can see the key is still present for mssql-server.

Is there a way to resync these packages so I can remove them properly?

Comment: See how big your stored cache of packages (installed and removed) is: `sudo du -h /var/cache/apt/archives/`. If it's big enough to make a difference, reduce the cache with `sudo apt autoclean` or delete the cache completely with `sudo apt clean`. Generally, it's inefficient to free up space by deleting packages -- most packages are too small to bother. Most folks' entire local package cache is much smaller than one movie.

Comment: Sadly, it's only 256K, my root partition is 40GB. I think the packages are the main issue. Is there any way to find out what is using all of the root partition memory?

Comment: Seems like you have conclusively shown that 256K of packages are lot NOT the main issue. Largest space-hogs on your disk: See https://superuser.com/questions/9847/linux-utility-for-finding-the-largest-files-directories

Comment: Got my answer. Docker images and containers were taking up almost 8GB on my system. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Apt was not the issue here. I was able to find the issue using an application called FileLight. I had to run it with sudo so that it could access all of my root partition.

This showed that Docker was taking up almost 8 Gigabytes with images and containers.